# Excel - Conditional Formatting, Multiple Conditions & !=

Tags: excel, xlsx

What is the proper formatting for the following multi-conditional format?

Neither of these work:

=($L4=$X4) and ($K4<>$W4), or
=AND($L4=$X4),($K4<>$W4))

Also != does not help.

I want to paste this condition to all rows in Col (L)

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: it should be `=AND(($L4=$X4),($K4<>$W4))`

Answer (score 0):

Your formulas work for me once I fix the parenthesis. Did you mean =AND(($L4=$X4),($K4<>$W4))?
Put that in L4, and you can then use the format painter to pull it down.